# Is Binance a scam exchange/wallet?

Tags: exchanges, fraud

Now 5 days ago, I initiated a transfer from my Bittrex account to Binance, using Binance's ID code snip and the receiving Address code snip. The coin was immediately removed from my Bittrex a/c but is yet to appear in my newly created Binance a/c. Worse yet, after five postings to Binance Support, I am yet to receive any human reply regarding the missing deposit, only the auto-generated robo responses when the support ticket is submitted. I'm about ready to contact a legal authority about Binance, but I believe it may be a Japanese or Chinese enterprise. Is there any "global" policing authority, such as the USA's SEC or FCC that could take actions against potential scam operations regardless of where that operation's home office might be located?

Comment: Hey did you ever get the transfer or a reply from support. I'm afraid I may be in a similar boat.

Comment: A full 5 hours on top of my original and no, no deposit, no response from Support after multiple inquiries about it. The site looks dead in the water. I noticed that they were saying, for instance, that Monero (XMR) was suspended for withdrawals due to "Wallet Maintenance." Same status as when I made my deposit on 12 December. Not feeling very good about this outfit. And if they go another week without acknowledging my deposit, or at least having a human respond to my support requests, I'll be looking for some legal recourse.

Comment: No official phones, no offices ("for security" reasons, even banks have), you can't contact them, it's a ghost company. Their online support copy & paste wall of meaningless text replying not on topic. They refuse to give any legal contact. They holding my funds, and they do not cooperate. Support rarely understand what's being asked. How to sue them? Do you've to go for their [CEO](https://cryptovest.com/news/binance-founder-taken-to-court-by-sequoia-capital/)?

Comment: Related: [BINANCE: Withdrawal Refuse Alert - Reason:Security Risk](https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/acurws/binance_withdrawal_refuse_alert_reasonsecurity/).

Answer (score 4):

At this time I would think that they are. They have no concept of customer support and they are very unprofessional. If you need support and need them to fix something, they will delay and delay until you are desperate and then they come up to you for paid support.

I contacted support for days and days and when i finally got response, it was that I had to pay them ETH for service or say bye to my money.

I deal with many crypto exchanges and this was a new for me. After I agreed, I was then told it would take a month for me to access my own coins because dev team is supposedly tired from working.

So yeah if you mess up anywhere expect either to pay for support or never see your funds.

Answer (score 1):

I have transferred from gdax to binance to buy coins and have never had a problem. From what you have said I don't think you have a clue what you were doing, you probably used the wrong address. They are a scam in no way, if they were all my many transactions would not have gone through. The onus is on you to know what you're doing I'm afraid.

Comment: Why don't they reply then?